# Android React native cache and storage space

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, caching, local-storage

I created a simple application, which uses the following modules:

```
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.12",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-material-menu": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
    "react-native-super-grid": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^12.0.2",
    "sharingan-rn-modal-dropdown": "^1.4.0"
```

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  ImageBackground,
  StatusBar,
  Dimensions,
  ScrollView,
  DrawerLayoutAndroid,
} from 'react-native';
import cio from 'cheerio';
import {
  Card,
  Text,
  Button,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Chip,
  TextInput,
  List,
} from 'react-native-paper';
import { FlatGrid } from 'react-native-super-grid';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { Dropdown } from 'sharingan-rn-modal-dropdown';
import { Menu, MenuItem } from 'react-native-material-menu';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
```

In this application I simply do a fetch to fetch the information and then display the information and related image.

Whenever I go to look into the app storage, I always notice that there is data and cache adding to your background.

Getting heavier and heavier, being that I don't store any information in the storage, I wonder:

1. What kind of data is it?
2. Who stores this data?
3. Is there a way that once the app is closed, this data is automatically emptied?

Comment: Can you share more details of the code that is fetching the data?

Comment: I do a simple fetch and then using cheeriojs I parse the HTML string to get the information.

And then I show the information which is some text and the reference image.